# Why is it always night in the other world?

Tags: plot-explanation, coraline

So I have been doing some studying of the movie *Coraline*. Something that I can't figure out is why it is always night in the other world.

There are multiple times this is shown. After other Wybie saves Coraline from inside the mirror he takes her to the corridor, if you pay close attention you can see that it is night, but when she returns home it is day. More proof is when Coraline's mother goes to get groceries and Coraline goes back through the door, when she arrives in the other world you can find that it is night. How is this possible?

Comment: Possibly because the other world has no sun? (doing it as a comment instead of answer seeing i honestly don't know this one, only watched it once because it kinda creeped me out)

Answer (score 1):

The other world is fully controlled by the

> creature that initially poses as Coraline's mom.

So she can do whatever she wants with the day and night cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Likely because Coraline typically goes there at night, so the Beldam created the world in a facade of night for her. It would be a waste of energy to add a daytime version, rather than just leaving it night, since the normal time for Coraline to enter is evening, and by the time she's entering during the day, she already knows it's a lie.